# Non-cacheable memory explanation

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture

I couldn't find a very clear explanation for the term "non-cacheable memory". I would be grateful if anyone could help me in this way.

Comment: Provide the exact context in which you found the term. Also include in the question what explanations aren't clear to you and why.

Comment: Normally (e.g. for x86) it's a memory region where the CPU is configured not to do caching.  In x86, it also means reads and writes to it are a visible side-effect of execution, like `volatile` in C, disallowing speculative loads, like you need for MMIO.  The asm equivalent of C `volatile` is actually a really good analogy.